# Dark Souls II - Scholar of the first sin "Failed to save game"

Tags: dark-souls-2-sotfs

I transfered my old save games to folder in appdata. All works great but when i click load my old character I see windows:
1. Loading save's data
2. Saving save's data
3. Failed to save game

I know that save could be corrupted. But it's the same steamID and i can check my character stats in "Continue" menu so I hope that can be solution for it. Maybe someone have an idea?

Comment: Where are the old saves from?

Comment: I.e. are they from Dark Souls 2, or SotFS?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't mentioned that I lost that file and recover by deep scaning program, so this file doesn't have "normal" settings. I righ clicked and unchecked readonly mode on my old save game and works :D